# ndk_build.cmd in cygwin not recognizing included mk files

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cygwin, ndk-build

I have multiple static libs that are built using jni. I have a scheme that includes other mk files, etc to allow me to share compile settings, include files from other dependent projects, etc.

I have set it up successfully on the mac and have been building it. However, when I tried to do the same in windows under cygwin I'm running into issues...

Here is my jni/Android.mk file..

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
INJ_PROJECT_PATH := $(PWD)
include $(INJ_PROJECT_PATH)/jni/Project.mk
```

The problem I'm seeing is that ndk-build is complaining about the Project.mk file. Here is what I'm seeing..

```
shammi@SHAMMIDEV /cygdrive/c/projects/injitiProjects/injitiEngine/Engine/Core
$ ndk-build.cmd NDK_APP_OUT=../../build/Android/Engine/release
jni/Android.mk:5: /cygdrive/c/projects/injitiProjects/injitiEngine/Engine/Core/jni/Project.mk: No such file or directory
jni/Android.mk:5: /cygdrive/c/projects/injitiProjects/injitiEngine/Engine/Core/jni/Project.mk: No such file or directory
jni/Android.mk:5: /cygdrive/c/projects/injitiProjects/injitiEngine/Engine/Core/jni/Project.mk: No such file or directory
jni/Android.mk:5: /cygdrive/c/projects/injitiProjects/injitiEngine/Engine/Core/jni/Project.mk: No such file or directory
C:/projects/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-all.mk:89: Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!
make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/projects/injitiProjects/injitiEngine/Engine/Core/jni/Project.mk'.  Stop.
```

I have confirmed that /cygdrive/c/projects/injitiProjects/injitiEngine/Engine/Core/jni/Project.mk does exist, and I am the owner and it has read permissions for user/group/other.

Again, this exact same setup works absolutely fine on the mac. I'm just looking at having a portable dev environment.

What am I missing here..?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I forgot that ndk-build.cmd was a windows shell batch script (DOH).
The answer was that I was able to call /build/ndk-build which is a sh script that is comfortable running in cygwin.

Comment: ndk-build.cmd should work in Cygwin though. I was actually planning on removing the shell script version because all the cygwin support in the shell version is really poor, but the batch file with cygwin worked fine when I tried it. I think the issue is that you used `$(PWD)` instead of `$(LOCAL_PATH)`.

Comment: I believe the reason I did $(PWD) was to get the full path as opposed to a relative path. I might have overdone the system, but it allows for all my libs to share common settings and provides ability to customize via files like Source.mk, AdditionalIncludes.mk, and Target.mk, etc. I ended up fixing the $(PWD) earlier with $(shell pwd) and having a pwd batch script earlier, but ran into other issues compiling it in Windows and decided to try out cygwin instead. Regardless, it's working now. Please don't remove the sh script that's in there now. I am using it successfully :)

Comment: Generally if there are options you want to apply to all your code they should go in Application.mk. i.e. `APP_CFLAGS := -DMY_DEFINE=foo`. I'll need to try to come up with a test case for your situation and see if I can get it to behave with cygwin when using ndk-build.cmd.

Comment: Would you like me to send you my code/project structure? On a side note, where would be the best place to specify NDK_APP_OUT. Specifying it in Application.mk ignores it for the first platform that is built. I tried other places unsuccessfully and finally resorted to supplying it with the ndk-build command. It would be nice to have it be in the mk files.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `LOCAL_PATH` instead of `PWD`. I'm not really sure how `PWD` gets set (I think it's a make builtin?), but we actually have control over LOCAL_PATH and can make sure it gets set in the right way for cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of include what if you define it to be APP_BUILD_SCRIPT?

for ex.

APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := jni/Android.mk

Also Id try $(shell $pwd)  instead of $(PWD)  if the above doesn't work,  usually ndk doesn't interpret shell commands for me if I don't use the shell in  the parenthesis.

Comment: I did end up using your $(shell pwd) solution earlier successfully. However, I ran into other issues that were caused by the environment differences caused by the shell, and decided to try cygwin instead. Regardless, it seems to be working now that I'm using the ndk-build script under the build folder.